# How do I fix this size of tensor error for my NN classifier PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm having trouble understanding why this is throwing an error. This code is pulled directly from the PyTorch documentation for a NN classifier for the fashion MNIST dataset. However when I try to flip this to the MNIST handwritten digits data set it comes up with the following error:

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1

This occurs when using the loss function during the training loop function. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening. Thanks!

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Lambda
import torchvision.models as models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
#device = "cpu"
print(f"Using {device} device")

training_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

test_data = datasets.MNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=64)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=64)

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28*28, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 10),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits

def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
        pred = model(X)
        
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
        
        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")


def test_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()

    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")
    
def save_checkpoint(state, filename = "checkpoint.pth.tar"):
    print("=> Saving checkpoint")
    torch.save(state, filename)

model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)

learning_rate = 1e-3
batch_size = 64
epochs = 10

# Initialize the loss function
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimiser)
    test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")
```

Comment: In the future, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.nn.MSELoss` is an implemention of mean squared error. You can't measure the difference between two tensors if they're different sizes (`MSELoss` does *not* allow for broadcasting). So if you're using `MSELoss`, then the predictions and the targets must be the same shape. In your case, `preds` is a tensor of shape `[64, 10]`, and `y` is a tensor of shape `[64]`.

The reason `y` is of shape `[64]` rather than `[64, 10]` is that most classification dataset implementations represent targets as integer labels rather than one-hot encoded vectors. In theory, you *could* convert these integer label targets to one-hot encoded targets.

But in reality, since this is a classification problem, you should probably be using something like `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` rather than `nn.MSELoss`. The former is a conventional classification loss function, and it allows the targets to be integer labels rather than one-hot labels (so just swapping out `MSELoss` for `CrossEntropyLoss` should solve your problem). `MSELoss` is better suited for regression tasks and such.